# How to escape it properly?

Tags: javascript, sql, string, escaping

I have sql string written with template string syntax:

```
const sql = `select * from tbl_name where smth=$1 name like '%$2%'`;

const data = await execute(sql, [something, someName]);
```

I have problems with binding second param - $2 because of single quote. How should I write it properly ?

Error: `Error: Query failed: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`

Comment: Single quotes don't need to be escaped in a back-tick string. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: added error msg to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're supposed to use wildcards this way:

```
const sql = `select * from tbl_name where smth=$1 name like $2`;
const data = await execute(sql, [something, `%${someName}%`]);
```